# How to enlarge and shrink an element in a loop animation through jquery or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've an image that will be moving up and down in an animation loop and it’s shadow element will shrink and enlarge accordingly. This will create an effect like the object is suspending in air. I’d attached a reference image in the following link -

http://s28.postimg.org/k3mioxzel/sample_image.jpg

I’d made the image moving up and down through jQuery with the following code and its working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('#myImg').load(function(){    
      setInterval(function(){
        $('#myImg').animate({'marginTop':"-=35px"},"slow");            
        $('#myImg').animate({'marginTop':"+=35px"},"slow");
        },1000/30);   
  });
});
```

But I can’t enlarge or shrink the shadow element along with the image movement. I’d created the shadow element in CSS  code. Please help me in this.

```
#oval {
    width: 226px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #d8b54c;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: -113px;
    -moz-border-radius: 226px / 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 226px / 50px;
    border-radius: 226px / 50px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick, modify the `width`/`height`/`marginTop` and `marginBottom` increments/decrements as needed: ([Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KMpUm/8/))

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('#myImg').load(function(){    
      setInterval(function(){
        $('#myImg').animate({'marginTop':"-=35px"},"slow");            
        $('#myImg').animate({'marginTop':"+=35px"},"slow");
        },1000/30);  
      setInterval(function(){
        $('#oval').animate({'width': "-=10px",'height': "-=10px",
                            'marginTop': "+=5px", 'marginLeft': "+=5px" 
         }, "slow");
        $('#oval').animate({'width': "+=10px", 'height': "+=10px",
                            'marginLeft': "-=5px",'marginTop': "-=5px"
                           }, "slow");
      }, 1000 / 30);
});
```

Comment: Hi SARI ALALEM, Sorry, I need one more tweak in the oval animation, now the oval width and height is increasing by 10 pixels on right and bottom direction. How can I increase and decrease the oval size in all four directions?

Comment: I've updated the answer and the jsfiddle example to what you are asking for. If this is what you need, please mark the answer as the correct one.

Comment: THANKS A LOT SARI ALALEM! Now its working exactly what i need, i.e, the oval is expanding and shrinking in all four sides. I noted the margin-top and margin-left you have updated. Thanks. I have marked the answer as the correct one :)

Comment: if you want to change the numbers for the oval, here is the math:  `marginLeft = width/2`, `marginTop=height/2`